# Get Next Value of an occurrence

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Database : Redshift

I have a table with the following data

```
**Term      priority**
Search    4
Search    2
Input     5
Input    13
Search   10
Search   20
Search   22
```

My objective is to get count of values where previous term was `search` and next term was `Input` based on priority (ASC).

So basically my query should sort the table to below format

```
SlNo  **Term      priority**
    1    Search    2
    2    Search    4
    3    Input     5
    4    Search   10
    5    Input    13
    6    Search   20
    7    Search   22
```

And give me the count as 2, because - After SlNo(2) `Search` there is `Input` which makes count=1.
After SlNo(4) `Search` there is `Input` which makes count = 2

Is there any way to achieve this in redshift ?

Comment: Do you need the sorted table or only the count?? if you need both tables and count then can it be done by two query or you want it done by a single one??

Comment: @sagarchapagain I only need the count

Comment: Is it possible to write stored procedure or you need a plain sql query??

Answer (score 0):

I created this query on Oracle however I believe Redshift has similar functionality: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LEAD.html

```
WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT 'Search' AS term, 4  AS priority FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Search' AS term, 2  AS priority FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Input' AS  term, 5  AS priority FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Input' AS  term, 13 AS priority FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Search' AS term, 10 AS priority FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Search' AS term, 20 AS priority FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Search' AS term, 22 AS priority FROM dual
)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT input_data.*, LEAD(term, 1) OVER (ORDER BY priority) AS next_term
  FROM input_data
) a
WHERE term = 'Search' AND next_term = 'Input'
;
```

Output:

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 2        |
+----------+
```